# sending multiple products via paypal

Tags: html, paypal

I would like to send multiple products to paypal.
I know that the format of sending products to payPal is:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="item_name_x" value="test 1">
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work.
What do you think the problem is?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
            <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
                <input type="hidden" name="business" value="ronny@hoojima.com">
                <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="test 1">
                <input type="hidden" name="item_number_1" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="test 2">
                <input type="hidden" name="item_number_2" value="2">
                <input type="hidden" name="item_name_3" value="test 3">
                <input type="hidden" name="item_number_3" value="3">
                <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="99.00">
                <input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="2">
                <input type="hidden" name="amount_3" value="99.00">
                <input type="image" name="submit" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/i/buttons/checkout-logo-large.png" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
            </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using PayPal Buy Now button you cannot pass the multiple items. For allowing multiple items to PayPal use the "cart upload" button code. Refer the following below sample code and links for your reference:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
        <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="paypalemail"><!-- Add your PayPal Seller/Business email address mandatory-->
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Item Name 1"> <!--  sample item name -->
        <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="1.00"><!--  sample amount -->
        <input type="hidden" name="shipping_1" value="1.75"><!--  sample shipping -->
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="Item Name 2">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="2.00">
        <input type="hidden" name="shipping_2" value="2.50">
        <input type='hidden' name='invoice' value='your Invoice Id' /> <!-- add Unique invoice for different customer -->
        <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="www.yourwebsite.com/ipn"> <!-- Please add IPN URL You can use this service to automate back-office and administrative functions, including fulfilling orders, tracking customers, and providing status and other information related to transactions. -->
        <input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='Your currency' />
        <input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='' /><!-- Take customers to this URL when they cancel their checkout -->
        <input type='hidden' name='return' value='' /><!-- Take customers to this URL when they finish their checkout  -->
        <input type="image" name="submit" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
    </form>
```

For PayPal button HTML variables refer the following link: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/

For Instant Payment Notification(IPN): https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/gs_IPN/

Answer (score 0):

Thank for the answer.
For making it generic from cart, you can use this like:

```js
function updateToPayPal() {
           var formChildren = $("#payPalInputs");
           var itemsInTable = $("#cartTable").find('tr');
           var j = 1;
           for (var i = 0; i < itemsInTable.length; i++) {

               var tr = itemsInTable[i];

            var qty = $(tr).find('.qtyInput').val();
            if(qty === undefined)
                continue;
               var price = $(tr).find('.total').text();
               var name = $(tr).find('.name').text();

               var itemName = $('<input type="hidden" name="item_name_' + j + '" value="' + name + '">');
               var itemPrice = $('<input type="hidden" name="amount_' + j + '" value="' + parseInt(price) + '">');
               var itemQty = $('<input type="hidden" name="quantity_' + j + '" value="' + qty + '">');
               j++;
               $(formChildren).append(itemName).append(itemPrice).append(itemQty);
           }
       }
```

```html
            <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" id="payPalInputs">
                <input type="submit" id="paypal" value=""> </input>
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
                <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="business" value="seller@dezignerfotos.com">
                <input type="hidden" name="image_url" value="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSh4ggvLtqBjp6ipc-tjwvkb1Cy62J8nTnhdNNCFrE-NMnU70B3">
            </form>

<table id="cartTable"><h2>Cart</h2><tr id="" title-row=""><th></th><th>Products</th><th>Qty</th><th>Price</th><th>Total</th></tr><tr id="Products0"><td class="deleteRow"><span>X</span></td><td class="name">Korean / American</td><td><input type="number" class="qtyInput" id="quantity" maxlength="3" size="3" value="1"></td><td>15.88</td><td id="total" class="total">79.4000</td></tr><tr id="Products1"><td class="deleteRow"><span>X</span></td><td class="name">Batman album</td><td><input type="number" class="qtyInput" id="quantity" maxlength="3" size="3" value="1"></td><td>53.59</td><td id="total" class="total">107.1800</td></tr><tr id="Products3"><td class="deleteRow"><span>X</span></td><td class="name">Gravity Falls</td><td><input type="number" class="qtyInput" id="quantity" maxlength="3" size="3" value="1"></td><td>105.64</td><td id="total" class="total">211.2800</td></tr><tr id="total-row"><td>Total</td><td></td><td id="totalQty">9</td><td></td><td id="totalBill">397.8600</td></tr></table>
```

with a dynamic cart that updated from user inputs